# want to extract a substring from last id

Tags: php, mysqli

i want to extract a substring from an id to get the last 3 
e.g:
PD1920005 - IDPSB

I want to get the last 3 numbers (005) from the last id.

here is the code

```
    <?php
    include 'koneksi.php';

         $query=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MAX(id) FROM psbsmp");
         $data=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
         $id= $data['id'];

                $psba=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT RIGHT(idpsb, 4) FROM psbsmp WHERE id='$id'");
                $data2=mysqli_fetch_array($psba);



            echo $data2;
?>
```

but the results I get are as follows:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Template\Login_v2\Login_v2\tes.php on line 12

What should I have to do for that? Please let me know any possible way.

Comment: What do you get when you do...`var_dump($data);`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate fix your problem is to alias `MAX(id)`:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM psbsmp");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$id = $data['max_id'];
```

But, you don't even need two separate queries here:

```
SELECT RIGHT(idpsb, 4)
FROM psbsmp
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM psbsmp);
```

Comment: ok thanks, but when implemented I got a notice:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Template\Login_v2\Login_v2\tes.php on line 20

Comment: "but when implemented" ... _what_ did you implement?  I can't see your latest code, therefore I can't comment.

Comment: `<?php
 include 'koneksi.php';
  
      $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT RIGHT(idpsb, 4) FROM psbsmp WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM psbsmp)");
   $data=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
   echo $data;
   
?>`

Comment: Run my second query (the one you are using) directly in MySQL.  Do you get back more than one row?

Comment: in MySQL, the result only one. but, when i'm using `var_dump($data);` i get this `array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "0007" ["RIGHT(idpsb, 4)"]=> string(4) "0007" }`

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but `echo $data[0]` should give the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code assuming you have predefined format same is this string. You should modify this as per your needs.

```
    $string='PD1920005 - DPSB';
    $string=str_replace(' ','',$string);
    $strArray=explode('-',$string);
    $numberToBeExtractedFrom=$strArray[0];
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $numberToBeExtractedFrom, $numbers);
    $numbersString=$numbers[0][0];
    $id=substr($numbersString, -3);
    echo $id;
```